# creating infinte reverse add then sort

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to create an infinte reverse add then sort list in haskell

```
r = map head (iterate rlist [2..])

rlist (x:xs) = [x : xs | x <- xs ,  x  quick $ p+x ]
                  where p = reverse x

quick [] = []
quick (x:xs) = quick [u |u <- xs, u < x] ++ [x] ++ quick [u | u <- xs , u >= x]
```

but its not working, any suggestions?

thanks.

Comment: Note: You propably want to use the `sort` from `Data.List`. Quicksort in Haskell *reads* great, but in fact it's `O(scary)`.

Comment: "But it's not working".  Please post more info about this.  Compile errors?  Runtime errors? Incorrect output?

Comment: It would help, if you specify what exactly you want to do. rlist is complete nonsense: there exists no type so that the type of x (both x) is a Number and a Function and a List at the same time. I'm not even sure wether you try to reverse an infinite list and then sort it?! ò_O

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you expect your code to work (perhaps there was a problem when you posted the code).  Namely, part of your list comprehension `... x quick $ p + x` makes no sense to me - `x` isn't a function and it isn't a list so `reverse x` also makes no sense.  For that matter you have shadowed `x` - notice the `x` in your list comprehension isn't the same as the `x` in `ratslist (x:xs)`.

A simple solution does exist using read and show to convert the numbers to lists of digits (well, characters, but it works) and back:

```
import Data.List

myRats = 1  : map ratify myRats
-- Alternatively: myRats = iterate ratify 1

ratify :: Integer -> Integer
ratify n = sortRat (n + rev n)
  where
  rev = read . reverse . show
  sortRat = read . sort . show
```

And in GHCi:

```
*Main Data.List> take 10 myRats
[1,2,4,8,16,77,145,668,1345,6677]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your problem, but according to your example, I'd try

```
rats x = sort (zipWith (+) x (reverse x))
```

like in `rats [1,4,5]` which equals `[6,6,8]`.